# Asp.net async db connection not reusing connections

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, ado.net

I have a .net mvc / sql server website for a high-traffic application. I'm using async database connections.

Prior to launch I ran a load test, and it blew up pretty quickly under load. The connection pool quickly ran out of connections.

Running sp_who at the database level shows a pile of connections sleeping awaiting command. If I switch to non-async, this does not happen.

So, it appears that new database calls are not using connections sitting in the connection pool, instead they are opening their own new connection. This quickly exhausts the connection pool limit, and begins timing out queries.

The following is the helper I'm using to execute an async datareader. Does anyone see any issue here?

```
private async Task<List<T>> ExecuteReaderAsync<T>(SqlCommand command, Func<SqlDataReader, T> rowConverter)
{
    List<T> ret = new List<T>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {                    
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                ret.Add(rowConverter(reader));
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I'm calling the code like the datareader helper like the following:

```
public async Task<Content> FindContentAsync(int id)
{
    Content content = null;
    using (SqlCommand command = CreateProcedure("dbo.FindContent"))
    {
        AddParam(command, "Id", SqlDbType.Int, id);
        List<Content> items = await ExecuteReaderAsync<Content>(command, x => BindContent(x));
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            content = items[0];
        }
    }
    return content;
}
```

And calling that from a helper:

```
    public async Task<Content> FindAsync(int id)
    {
        var db = new DataAccess();
        var content = await db.FindContentAsync(id);
        return content;
    }
```

Comment: You aren't using asynchronous connections. You are calling `Open` asynchronously.  This doesn't have any effect on the connection pool. Calling `Close` is also not needed since you are using `using`. Are you *sure* the method has finished though? Did you check IIS to see how many requests are still active? The connection pool has no default maximum, have you changed it?

Comment: Perhaps more important, what is the connection string? Connection pooling can be disabled with the proper parameter in the connection string.

Comment: Also note, the `Asynchronous Processing` parameter is ignored in .NET 4.5+ as it's no longer needed. There is no `asynchronous connection`, just asynchronous execution of commands

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I added close to see if the connection could be released earlier than through GC. Didn't seem to have an effect. The connection pool does have a default maximum - it's 100. Anyway, please feel free to answer with how my code should be structured.

Comment: And yes, this is .net 4.5, so Asynchronous Processing=True isn't required in the connection string.

Comment: `using` doesn't mean "use the CG", it means "close the connection immediately, don't wait for the CG". Anyway, the important thing is *how many queries are active at the same time*? 100 connections aren't too many if you have 100 queries executing concurrently. One way to do it is to check how many IIS requests are executing from inside IIS Manager. A better way is to use Visual Studio's Performance Profiler to profile your application. The profiler detects and times SQL queries as well so it's easy to see whether the query takes a long time or `rowConverter`'s cost adds up.

Comment: I'm running a load test through loader.io. I can run the exact same load test against the same query, one async and one not, and the async query piles up connections as revealed through running sp_who. Non-async does not. It's a simple query, runs quickly - < 10ms. The entire page loads in about 60ms. I really don't think it's anything to do with the query, but something with how I'm running the async code.

Comment: How do you call the async *method* then? Do you wait for it to finish or are you firing multiple tasks without waiting for them to finish? You may be executing a lot more queries than you think by accident

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I've updated my question with the calling code.

Comment: @ScottE did you find a resolution to this issue?  I think I'm experiencing something similar when I use async processing with a SqlConnection

Comment: No, I didn't find a resolution. I reverted to non-async.

Comment: @ScottE just taking a chance here :) did you happen to fix the issue with async calls to the db? I am also facing the exact same problem.